# Alternative to useState inside of event handlers with useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to only call an axios call once per render from an event handler (onClick basically), so I'm using useEffect and inside that useEffect, I'm using useState. Problem is - when onClick is called, I get the following error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

I understand why I'm getting it, I'm using useState in an event handler - but I don't know what else to do. How else can I handle these variables without useState?

HttpRequest.js

```js
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export function useAxiosGet(path) {
    const [request, setRequest] = useState({
        loading: false,
        data: null,
        error: false
    });
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setRequest({
            loading: true,
            data: null,
            error: false
        });
        axios.get(path)
            .then(response => {
                setRequest({
                    loading: false,
                    data: response.data,
                    error: false
                })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                setRequest({
                    loading: false,
                    data: null,
                    error: true
                });
                
                if (err.response) {
                    console.log(err.response.data);
                    console.log(err.response.status);
                    console.log(err.response.headers);
                } else if (err.request) {
                    console.log(err.request);
                } else {
                    console.log('Error', err.message);
                }
                console.log(err.config);
            })
    }, [path])
    
    return request
}
```

RandomItem.js

```js
import React, {useCallback, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Item from "../components/Item";
import Loader from "../../shared/components/UI/Loader";
import {useAxiosGet} from "../../shared/hooks/HttpRequest";
import {useLongPress} from 'use-long-press';

function collectItem(item) {
    return useAxiosGet('collection')
}

function RandomItem() {
    let content = null;
    let item;
    
    item = useAxiosGet('collection');
    console.log(item);
    
    const callback = useCallback(event => {
        console.log("long pressed!");
    }, []);
    const longPressEvent = useLongPress(callback, {
        onStart: event => console.log('Press started'),
        onFinish: event => console.log('Long press finished'),
        onCancel: event => collectItem(),
        //onMove: event => console.log('Detected mouse or touch movement'),
        threshold: 500,
        captureEvent: true,
        cancelOnMovement: false,
        detect: 'both',
    });
    
    if (item.error === true) {
        content = <p>There was an error retrieving a random item.</p>
    }
    
    if (item.loading === true) {
        content = <Loader/>
    }
    
    if (item.data) {
        return (
            content =
                <div {...longPressEvent}>
                    <Item name={item.data.name} image={item.data.filename} description={item.data.description}/>
                </div>
        )
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            {content}
        </div>
    );
}

export default RandomItem;
```

[use-long-press](https://github.com/minwork/use-long-press)

It works to load up the first item just fine, but when you try to cancel a long click (Basically the onClick event handler), it spits out the error above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree that it's complicated but I think I've got a goal: it is all about longPressEvent -> onCancel -> collectItem -> useAxiosGet chain. So event handler tries to instantiate hook only after some event occurs(`onCancel`)

Comment: @skyboyer that's exactly what's going on, you long click on a div and if you don't hold down the click, onCancel gets called. onCancel calls collectItem and that calls useAxiosGet. onCancel is essentially just an onClick event handler.

The issue is solely in the useAxiosGet function being called from an event handler.

Comment: @skyboyer - Ah, well-spotted. Jon, a [mcve] would have made that a **lot** more clear.

Comment: Instead of handling all of that inside a `useEffect` hook, you could create a function, handle it inside of that function and then return the function along with all of the data from your custom `useAxiosGet` hook. [Here's an example of how it can be done](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-browser-1we44)

Answer (score 1):

You need to redo your hook so it would not start loading unconditionally but instead return a callback that might be called to initiate loading at some moment:

```
const [loadCollections, { isLoading, data, error }] = useLazyAxiosGet('collections');

....
  onCancel: loadCollections
```

I propose to follow [approach that Apollo uses](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#usequery) when there is `useQuery` that starts loading instantly and `useLazyQuery` that returns callback to be called later and conditionally. But both share similar API so could be easily replaced without much updates in code.

Just beware that "immediate" and "lazy" version don't just differ by ability to be called conditionally. Say, for "lazy" version you need to decide what will happen on series calls to callback - should next call rely on existing data or reset and send brand new call. For "immediate" version there are no such a dilemma since component will be re-rendered for multiple times per lifetime, so it definitely *should not* send new requests each time.

Comment: The fundamental point is: You can't call hooks except from other hooks or component functions, and the call has to be **synchronous**. It's how React knows what hooks a component uses.

Answer (score 0):

A user in discord provided this solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-frog-9vim0?file=/src/App.js

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

const fetchDataFromApi = () => {
  return axios(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${
      1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
    }`
  ).then(({ data }) => data);
};

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(undefined);
  const [canCall, setCanCall] = useState(true);

  const handler = {
    onClick: useCallback(() => {
      if (canCall) {
        setCanCall(false); // This makes it so you can't call more than once per button click
        fetchDataFromApi().then((data) => {
          setData(data);
          setCanCall(true); // Unlock button Click
        });
      }
    }, [canCall]),
    onLoad: useCallback(() => {
      if (canCall) {
        setCanCall(false); // This makes it so you can't call more than once per button click
        fetchDataFromApi().then((data) => {
          setData(data);
          setCanCall(true); // Unlock button Click
        });
      }
    }, [canCall])
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handler.onLoad(); //initial call
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, " ", 2)}</pre>
      <button disabled={!canCall} onClick={handler.onClick}>
        fetch my data!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```